# Flutter : Target file "lib/main.dart" not found

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

When I perform a **flutter run** I get an error

Target file "lib/main.dart" not found.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this ?

Comment: What directory do you execute the command from. Please add the output of `flutter doctor` to your question.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can run any file from any DIR provided that you set the target file path, example:

```
flutter run -t lib/main_dev.dart
```

OR

```
flutter run lib/dev/main_dev.dart
```

**UPDATE (2020 February 5th)**

*It is however not advisable to remove **main.dart** from your project.*

I'm sure most of you found this link because you are setting up / configuring your app to accommodate for different environments e.g. dev, stg, beta and prod.

Example:

main_dev.dart:

```
void main() async {
  dynamic configuredApp = AppConfig(
    appName: 'Flutter',
    flavorName: 'development',
    appVersion: 1.0,
    apiBaseUrl: 'https://dev-api.example.com/'
  );

  runApp(App(configuredApp));
}
```

main.dart

```
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  final dynamic configuredApp;

  App(this.configuredApp);

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}
```

As it turns out some build steps will fail in Android Studio mostly Gradle related if you don't have a main.dart file and method main() {} referenced inside this file.

- Common build errors (AndroidX migrate, APK build etc.)
- More info / solutions below related to flutter build error: finished with non-zero exit value 1

1. [issuecomment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27593#issuecomment-533093623)
2. [issuecomment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27593#issuecomment-546064747)
3. [issuecomment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27593#issuecomment-557715868)

---

An alternative to `flutter run -t lib/main_dev.dart` 
in VS Code with the debugger tool.

- Click "Add Configuration" and add the following or add manually:

.vscode/launch.json

```
  "configurations": [

    {
      "name": "Flutter",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      // "args": ["--enable-software-rendering"]
      // "flutterMode": "profile", //debug //release 
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/lib/main_dev.dart"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Yep, it's working as expected. Thanks! flutter build apk lib/config/env_dev.dart

Comment: the second part is the best answer

Comment: this works very well, i did with manual path.

Comment: 3. issueComment solved for me. Thanks!

Comment: If some one having issue file not found. Change to this "program": "./lib/staging_main.dart".

Answer (score 17):

Flutter is looking for `main.dart` in `lib` folder while you must have had file inside any other package.

Best solution is to place your `main.dart` file just inside `lib` folder. Flutter run command will work then for sure.

**It worked for me.**

`main.dart` url should be:

```
<app dir>/lib/main.dart
```

Comment: What if it's in another location? since i am using different files to build my prod and dev environment.

Answer (score 9):

So basically when you execute this

```
 flutter run
```

Flutter tries to find `main.dart` in `/lib` directory.

So if you have a file that is present in some other child directory of `/lib` directory or has a different name like `result_page.dart`, you'd encounter this error.
Now, a lot of answers had suggested to either rename your file to `main.dart` or move it directly under `/lib` directory.

But you can actually simply run any file by simply providing the **target file's path from the current directory** like this -

```
flutter run --target=lib/customization/result_screen.dart
```

So this would simply execute my `result_screen.dart` file present under some other child directory called `customization`.

You can also generate the APK file following the same logic and the command would look like this -

```
flutter build apk --target=lib/customization/result_screen.dart --target-platform=android-arm64
```

where `--target-platform=android-arm64` is optional and is meant for 64-bit Android devices which helps in reducing APK size which otherwise would generate a fat APK including both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries. More info [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using vscode...

When the error occurs, the vscode folder occurs in the side bar. It has the launch.json file inside.

You can change the **"program": "..."** property in the launch.json file to run the .dart file in the directory where you want.

Answer (score 3):

This happened when I used Visual Studio Code. What I did to fix the problem was by editing the `.vscode/launch.json` file and change the value of `"program"` to the absolute path of my `main.dart` file (e.g. `C://...`).

Answer (score 3):

### If you are using VSCODE

Check folder **.vscode>launch.json** and add configuration: 

if you have it already change a **"program": "path of main.dart example: lib/main.dart"**

```html
 {
    "name": "Dart",
    "type": "dart",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "lib/main.dart"
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Make Sure that your `main.dart` inside lib folder directly not in another package or directory

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using visual code and you encounter this problem while debugging,
just go to launch.json, go to the location of where your flutter app is located, to the lib folder and then to the main.dart ,copy the path then add it to the text **program** in the launch.json as indicated on the photo below

[launch.json "program" path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg2sq.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you are having multiple iOS schemes then you could try like this:

`flutter run --flavor UserDev -t lib/user/dev/main_dev.dart`

For,

```
"configurations": [{
            "name": "User-Dev",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/user/dev/main_dev.dart",
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "UserDev"
            ]
        }]
```

Answer (score 1):

in android studio this wokrs for me

1. left click in main.dart
2. right click in profile main.dart

this executes an snapshot aplicaction to configure the root profile a run your app

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message, and it happened because I accidentally deleted the void main()

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58618151/2227743

Answer (score 0):

VSCode Users: Plese navigate to launch.json and replace the "Program" line with the following :

```
"Program":"${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}/lib/main.dart"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Debug Mode` in `vs code`, ensure that the `vs code` working folder is your `Flutter` project main folder.

If you want to change the `vs code` working folder, you can use the `File > Open Folder` menu or `Ctrl+O` shortcut.

When I change the folder, **It worked for me**.

Answer (score 0):

What my case was
I forgot to write code for calling main....

```
void main()
{
  runApp......
}
```

And doing this worked

Comment: I helped with the formatting of your post. Please double check yourself the suspicious "Void" vs "void", because I am not so sure of the actual syntax in this technology. [edit] in case you agree with my hunch.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `final FlutterDevice flutterDevice = await FlutterDevice.create`

The root cause is that the **ResidentRunner** we use to attach and do hot reloads will try to find a `main.dart` file when a target isn't announced. Attach doesn't provide a target, so it uses the default behavior always. As per [**DaceShuckerow**](https://github.com/DaveShuckerow).

This issue is still there on the **official** [Repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36982).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `VSCode` then try this method :
**Delete .vscode** folder in your project directory and rerun the program.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is struggling with this what worked for me is to recreate ios folder. And -t works regardless of the location of the target or name of the target and without any need to have main.dart in your lib folder.

To recreate ios folder

- rename ios folder to something like ios_old
- run => flutter create fakeApp
- open fakeApp, copy the ios folder to your project
- migrate changes from ios_old (if you had any changes)
- delete ios_old

Answer (score 0):

I think you already change the path of main.dart.If so You can drag and drop the main.dart file to lib folder.(lib/main.dart)

Answer (score 0):

you probably just changed location of main.dart
try running :
`flutter run yourPath/main.dart` or  whatever you named it